# installing phpunit on zend server

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-server

Hi All I have gone through many related question to this problem but I am still unable to get the solution. I have installed `Zend Server`. Now I want to install `PHPunit`. I have installed `pear` and then installed `PHPUnit`.

My Zend Server is installed at

```
C:\xyz\zend\ZendServer
```

My pear is installed at

```
C:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR
```

And PHPunit is installed at

```
C:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit
```

I have added `pear` path and even PHPUnit path to `Envrionmental PATH` variable.  Then I opened `php.ini` located at

```
C:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\etc
```

and set include_path as

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear;c:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit"
```

Now When I run command at cmd to create zend project, the project is created but I found this note too

```
Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing action will be created.
```

Some one please tell me what Am I doing wrong and where to set this include path???

Best Regards :-)

Comment: Try to add PHPUnit.bat to your Systempath in Windows

Comment: Are you absolutely sure PHPUnit can be found in the `C:\xyz\zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\pear` directory? If you look in that directory you should see a directory named PHPUnit, and within it should be the PHPUnit php src files. I ask, because it's unusual for PHPUnit to be with the *bin* directory.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Yes I am pretty sure :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do some old school debugging :)

```
$ zf create project ./one
Creating project at /path/to/one
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.
```

No PHPUnit!

Locate `path/zend-framework/bin/zf.php` and add near the top:

```
var_dump(get_include_path());
```

Now let's see what the include path looks like:

```
$ zf create project ./two
string(32) ".:/usr/share/php"
Creating project at /path/to/two
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created
```

My PHPUnit isn't in the `/usr/share/php` directory. Let's resolve that by adding PHPUnit to the include path.

e.g. If PHPUnit is in `/path/to/phpunit`, open the `php.ini` file and add it to the include path.

Third times a charm:

```
$ zf create project ./three
string(56) ".:/usr/share/php:/path/to/phpunit"
Creating project at /path/to/three
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
```

If you've edited the correct `php.ini`, the `var_dump()` you added to `zf.php` will now echo the include path with whatever you modified it to, which in my case it was correct, so now PHPUnit is working.

Now remove the debug code from `zf.php`